# Is it possible to use Java 7 with IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5 Trial

Tags: java-7, websphere-8

I have installed WAS 8.5 **Trial** version on Windows 7. I would like to deploy and run Java 7 application. Is it possible to do it?

I can not see "IBM WebSphere SDK for Java Technology Edition 7" in the IBM Installation Manager's feature list and there is no SDK 7 installed, yet.

```
>managesdk.bat -listAvailable
CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_64
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.

>
```

Has somebody managed to make WAS 8.5 Trial and Java 7 work together on Windows 7?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've just found one of the possible solutions...

1. Select the method *"Download Director or HTTP"* instead of *"Installation Manager (Recommended)"* at the download page of *Evaluate: IBM WebSphere Application Server*. Then you get a list of products to download which contains *"IBM WebSphere SDK Java 7, Installation Manager repository"*.
2. Select and Download all parts of the product and extract the three part to the same directory.
3. Start your previously installed *Installation Manager* and add the directory as a new repository under *File > Preferences > Repositories*, then press OK.
4. Now you can choose *Install* and you can select *IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional)* from the list of available packages.

After the installation is completed you can check if everything went well.

```
>managesdk.bat -listAvailable
CWSDK1003I: Available SDKs :
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.6_64
CWSDK1005I: SDK name: 1.7_64
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.

>
```

The Java SDK 1.7 is installed and you can set it as the default SDK in the *Administrative Console* of your server.

```
Server > WebSphere application servers > server > Server Infrastructure  > Java SDKs
```

*Sorry for the stupid question, I wasn't careful enough...*

Comment: If it comes to IBM, it is never trivial to find the proper documentation and installable files.

Comment: Agree. This was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly install the JDK 1.7 or any required version supported.(find the available using the command - managesdk.bat -listAvailable)

Then Go to the Installed WAS Server DIR and then navigate to bin folder

`C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02\bin`

For ALL Profiles

```
managesdk -enableProfileAll -sdkname SDK_Name -enableServers
```

From there execute this command(In Windows)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer_2\profiles\AppSrv02\bin>managesdk
.bat -enableProfile -profileName AppSrv02 -sdkname 1.7_64
```

It gives this message to confirm.
CWSDK1017I: Profile AppSrv02 now enabled to use SDK 1.7_64.
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.

(In Linux)

```
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/WSRR/v8.5/bin/managesdk.sh -enableProfile -profileName AppSrv02 -sdkname 1.7_64
```

Note: AppSrv02 is the server name used in my local. Replace the name with your actual thing.