# Servlet project ear not getting published in WAS 8.5

Tags: java, servlets, rad, websphere-8

I am trying out a simple servlet example from this [**link**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example.htm) in RAD 8.5. Application server is WAS 8.5 .

The project name is HelloWorld and the ear is HelloWorldEAR . When ever i try to publish the ear, i keep getting this error :

`The HelloWorld project is built with Java SDK 7, which is not compatible with the server running at Java SDK 6. Try publishing the application on a later version of WebSphere Application Server.  Or try increasing the JRE of the server, if you are using WebSphere Application Server V8.5`

The `web.xml` code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Can anyone tell me what i can do to get rid of this problem ?

Comment: I dunno, compile with JDK6?  or change the JRE to JDK7

Comment: Which Jre ? where and how do i change it ?

Comment: Have a look at this page http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e14142/jdk7.htm

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606206/is-it-possible-to-use-java-7-with-ibm-websphere-application-server-8-5-trial or better this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014869703

Comment: is this issue fixed? @TheDarkKnight

Comment: @SireeshYarlagadda :   No, I used tomcat since I needed to use simple servlets .